# transition using activity + fragment and cardview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-cardview

I am so struggling hard to find how to come up with the design and implementation of showing cardview so that when a user click a cardview to detailActivity then there must be a [transition][1]. below is the link of the animation. Please help me
http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Vv4SxVSI2DY/VEqQxAf3PWI/AAAAAAAAA7c/mfq7XBrIGgo/s1600/activity_transitions%2B(1).gif

Answer (score 0):

you can use cardviews in recyclerview with its `LayoutManager`as `GridLayoutManager` and those type of transitions are available in Lollipop and newer versions of android. if you want those transitions in pre-lollipop devices too,you can use this library https://github.com/takahirom/PreLollipopTransition